# Return a Table using a Scalar Valued Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this function and I want return the table @List.
How I can do this? Anyone can help me.
Thank you

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTotalFaltasPorMes]
(
    -- PARÂMETROS
    @UIFuncionario as char(36),
    @Data as DateTime
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    -- VARIÁVEIS
    DECLARE @TotalFaltas as float
    DECLARE @List TABLE(Jan VARCHAR(100), Fev VARCHAR(100), Mar VARCHAR(100), Abr VARCHAR(100),
                        Mai VARCHAR(100), Jun VARCHAR(100), Jul VARCHAR(100), Ago VARCHAR(100),
                        Stb VARCHAR(100), Otb VARCHAR(100), Nov VARCHAR(100), Dez VARCHAR(100)
                        );

    -- QUERY SQL
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='1'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0

    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='2'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)

    INSERT INTO @List (Fev) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='3'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Mar) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='4'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Abr) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='5'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Mai) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='6'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Jun) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='7'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Jul) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='8'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Ago) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='9'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Stb) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

        SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='10'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Otb) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

        SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='11'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Nov) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='12'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Dez) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    -- RETORNO
    RETURN @List

END
```

Comment: What is the your problem (error)?

Comment: just so you know. Your code is terrible. No matter which value you pass as the parameter @Data, you will get the same result. And you are also missing an insert for first month. You should not return a table because the only information you return is 1 value.

Comment: Table valued functions with more than a single query are called multi statement table valued functions and the performance is truly hideous. Just tossing a bunch of queries together and sticking the results into a temp table and returning it is a recipe for super duper sloooooow code. You could rewrite this whole thing into a single select statement by the looks of it instead of a whole mess of select statements like this.

Comment: did any of the answers help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTotalFaltasPorMes]
(
    -- PARÂMETROS
    @UIFuncionario as char(36),
    @Data as DateTime
)
RETURNS @List TABLE(Jan VARCHAR(100), Fev VARCHAR(100), Mar VARCHAR(100), Abr VARCHAR(100),
                        Mai VARCHAR(100), Jun VARCHAR(100), Jul VARCHAR(100), Ago VARCHAR(100),
                        Stb VARCHAR(100), Otb VARCHAR(100), Nov VARCHAR(100), Dez VARCHAR(100)
                        )
AS
BEGIN

-- QUERY SQL
INSERT INTO @List(Jan)
SELECT SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
AND MONTH(@Data)=1
AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)

INSERT INTO @List (Fev)
SELECT SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
AND MONTH(@Data)=2
AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)

--... rest of your bad code
-- RETORNO
RETURN

END
```

Answer (score 0):

if I am correct, I think you have to do a Select statement to return the values. You cannot just add a code Return @List. Try adding a select statement and you should get the data in the @LIst

Answer (score 0):

Table Value Functions

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTotalFaltasPorMes]
(
    -- PARÂMETROS
    @UIFuncionario as char(36),
    @Data as DateTime
)
RETURNS @List TABLE
(Jan VARCHAR(100), Fev VARCHAR(100), Mar VARCHAR(100), Abr VARCHAR(100),
                        Mai VARCHAR(100), Jun VARCHAR(100), Jul VARCHAR(100), Ago VARCHAR(100),
                        Stb VARCHAR(100), Otb VARCHAR(100), Nov VARCHAR(100), Dez VARCHAR(100)
                        )
AS
BEGIN
    -- VARIÁVEIS
    DECLARE @TotalFaltas as float

    -- QUERY SQL
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='1'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0

    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='2'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)

    INSERT INTO @List (Fev) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='3'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Mar) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='4'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Abr) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='5'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Mai) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='6'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Jun) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='7'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Jul) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='8'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Ago) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='9'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Stb) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

        SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='10'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Otb) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

        SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='11'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Nov) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    SET @TotalFaltas=0
    SELECT @TotalFaltas=SUM(Duracao) FROM CthAcmDiaLG
    WHERE UIFuncionario=@UIFuncionario
    AND MONTH(@Data)='12'
    AND TpSegmento IN (6,7)
    INSERT INTO @List (Dez) VALUES (@TotalFaltas)

    -- RETORNO
    RETURN;

END
```

if you want an inline table valued function then you need to modify this to the following template

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTotalFaltasPorMes]
(
    -- PARÂMETROS
    @UIFuncionario as char(36),
    @Data as DateTime
)
RETURN (
--your query goes here
);
```